# How can I change Navigation Drawer default images..?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation, navigation-drawer

I want to change default images of Navigation Drawer.when  I'm doing modifications it's not working,why it's happening like that I don't know  please help me Stack over flow,Thanks.

```
enter code here
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: You're trying to initialize an array with an empty string.

Comment: new String{"one", "two", "three"}

Comment: Actually I am trying to get data from the database. So I kept the array with empty string.@vucko.

Comment: Could you please elaborate @laser. I could not get you.

Comment: What "data" is returned from the database?  When you initialise an array you have to declare its size or populate it with an array of Strings `{"one","two", "three"}` - this `String[] rollNumber = "";` does neither.

Comment: Thank you. But could you please give a solution for this issue@Mark.

Comment: ... We can't until more information is provided - What Data is returned from the database - provide an example?

Comment: There are hundreds of databases. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: I am referring to my local database@Laser.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList leave String array. ArrayList give you more feasibility to perform crud operations.

Just Like..

```
Arraylist<String> array = new ArrayList<>;
     while(cursor.moveToNext()){
     String rollNo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ROLL_NUMBER"));
     array.add(rollNo);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this..

```
     String[] array = new String[cursor.getCount()];
     int index = 0;
     while(cursor.moveToNext()){
     String uname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PLAYERNAME"));
     array[index] = uname;
     index++;
    }
```

**BUT** for situations like this.. there is [`ArrayList`](http://www.javatpoint.com/ArrayList-in-collection-framework)

Answer (score 0):

you must have to initalize string array or you have to specify value at a time

Example1:
  String strArr[] =new String[10];

Example2:

String strArr[]={"value1","value2"....};